# jquery Lightbox events not firing

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am developing a lightbox with thumbnails this is for learning process. I am having following issues with my code:

1. The events are not firing after the overlay appears. which has content added to it through jquery.( it would be great if you could explain also why it's not firing the event handlers).

   2. Is there a similar simple lightbox out there good for learning purpose.

Here is the code :

```js
$(function(){

  var thumbCode = $('.thumbnails').clone() //getting thmbnails html

      ,closeBtn = "<span class='closeBtn'>&times; CLOSE</span>" // code for close button

      ,displayArea = "<div class='imgDisArea'><img class='fullImg'></div>"
      ,imgSrc



  $('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {
    var clickedThumbnailSrc = $(this).data('src'); // value of data-src of clicked thumbnail
    $('<div class="bg-overlay"></div>').appendTo('body').fadeIn(300,drawContent(clickedThumbnailSrc)); 
  });

  // Creating display of light box;

  function drawContent(disImgSrc) {

    $('.bg-overlay').append(closeBtn).append(displayArea).append(thumbCode);
    $('.bg-overlay img.thumbnail').removeClass('thumbnail').addClass('lb-thumb');
    changeImgSrc(disImgSrc); 
  }

  $('.lb-thumb').on('click', function() {
    console.log('overlay thumbs clicked');
    var clickedThumbnailSrc = $(this).data('src'); // value of data-src of clicked thumbnail
    changeImgSrc(disImgSrc);
  });

  function changeImgSrc (disImgSrc) {
    $('img.fullImg').attr('src',disImgSrc);
  };

  $('.closeBtn').on('click', function(){
    console.log('close clicked');
    $('.bg-overlay').remove();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* lb container styles */

.lb {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

/* galery thumbnail styles */

ul.thumbnails {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  list-style: none;

}

ul.thumbnails li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.thumbnails li img.thumbnail {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

ul.thumbnails li img.thumbnail:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* backgournd overlay */

.bg-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1090;
}

.closeBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top:20px;
  z-index: 2010;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imgDisArea{
  height: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

img.lb-thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lb">

  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li><img class="thumbnail" src="_images/kofidasw1cc-nathan-anderson.jpg" data-src="_images/kofidasw1cc-nathan-anderson.jpg" width="100" height="100"></li>
    <li><img class="thumbnail" src="_images/PK_Vivi_Gerusalemme_ora_TESTATA_1280x720_1.jpg" data-src="_images/PK_Vivi_Gerusalemme_ora_TESTATA_1280x720_1.jpg" width="100" height="100"></li>
    <li><img class="thumbnail" src="_images/rk7z5yqmcko-james-sutton.jpg" dta-src="_images/rk7z5yqmcko-james-sutton.jpg" width="100" height="100"></li>
    <li><img class="thumbnail" src="_images/xqv9qdgosas-timothy-meinberg.jpg" data-src="_images/xqv9qdgosas-timothy-meinberg.jpg" width="100" height="100"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: I know a simple way to create a lightbox with CSS only if you want ?

Comment: Please, do share the link to it.

Comment: I'll answer with it, it will be easier to explain ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple lightbox with **CSS only** (*if it fits your project*):
You have to create 2 blocks:

```css
#normal {
        max-width: 50%;
        height: 200px;
    }

    #lightbox {
        /* First, we hide the lightbox block */
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    #lightbox img {
        max-width: 80%;
     max-height: 75%;
     margin-top: 5%;
    }

    /* When the lightbox is the target of a link, we display it */
    #lightbox:target {
        display: block;
        outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<a id="normal" href="#lightbox">
        <img src="https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder965/500x/55103965.jpg">
    </a>
    <a id="lightbox" href="#_">
        <img src="https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder965/500x/55103965.jpg">
    </a>
```

This is an example, there is many ways to do lightboxes and it's highly customizable. I'm actually using this method for a big project, it works pretty well, including comments in the lightbox (similar as what facebook does with its lightbox).
[A Codepen which use this](http://codepen.io/gschier/pen/HCoqh)
[MDN - CSS :target selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)